# How to find the offset of an element with respect to another element with Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

My requirement is a simple drag and drop. I want to find the offset values for my drop position with relative to the drag element position so that it would work for all display resolutions.
I have tried getLocation() function on the drop element but when I run the script it does not move to the accurate location. Its possibly because my elements are within multiple iframes. 
Is there a way for me to capture the location with respect to the last iframe it is within or to capture the offset values from my drag element?

Edit :
My to element is a canvas and i have to make sure it is dropped exactly at the center. I used below code to find the center. Correct me if I'm wrong. The element does not get dropped to the center or anywhere near for that matter. Both my element are within multiple iframes. Can this be the cause?

```
WebElement dragElement= workflowModeler.iconTask;
WebElement toElement = workflowModeler.workflowCanvas;
int offsetX = (toElement.getLocation().x + (toElement.getSize().width / 2));
int offsetY = (toElement.getLocation().y + (toElement.getSize().height / 2));

var Actions builder = new Actions(driver)
var Action dragAndMove = builder.clickAndHold(iconTaskElement).moveToElement(toElement).build()
var Action moveDown = builder.clickAndHold(iconTaskElement).moveByOffset(offsetX , offsetY).build()
var Action drop = builder.release().build()

dragAndMove.perform()
moveDown.perform()
drop.perform()
```

Comment: Can you share your research please? Thanks

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, I edited my post. Please take a look now.

Comment: Can you show us the `workflowModeler` class please? Thanks

Comment: It is a basic Page Object class containing the web elements. I can assure that the elements were properly caught from the XPATH